# how can i extract the start time and end time from an rrdtool acrchive?

Tags: rrdtool

I have been given several rrd filed containing cpu load for about a year.

using rrdtool info  I do see a last_update. would that be the last data point added?  If so, awesome, but I don't see anything that tells me the time of the first entry. I am looking to graph the entire year but looking for the start time via fetch is not practical on multiple files. I'd like to do it programmatically if possible.

thanks for your time, 
J

Comment: ok I figured it out i need rrdtool first  and rrdtool last.   can this be marked closed? sorry for jumping the gun.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `lastupdate` command will give the time that the last data sample came in via `rrdtool update`.

The `last` command will give you the time of the last consolodated data point in a specified RRA, and the `first` command gives the first point in time for that RRA.

Note that these are not necessarily the same!  If your sample step is 300s, and your RRA consolodates 12 data points to make once consolodated data point (IE, one hour), then you may have a 'lastupdate' of 12:59 but a 'last' (for the hourly RRA) of 11:00 (as the 12:00 consolodated data point is not yet complete).

Of course, the 'first' point in time moves forward as historical data are expired, in line with the size of the RRA and the time width of the consolodated step.